# Runtime error. Multiple AVCaptureInputs not supported

Tags: swift, debugging

Camera torch gets turned on automatically as per my code but then the app crashes. Stuck on the launch screen with the torch still on.

The debugging green line break with signal SIGABRT is pointing to the AppDelegate.

[image]

[image]

I pasted as little code as possible. If you see the problem and tell me what I can trim from the question I will cut it out.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
var validFrameCounter: Int = 0

// for sampling from the camera
enum CurrentState {
    case statePaused
    case stateSampling
}
var currentState = CurrentState.statePaused

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
    for device in devices {
        // Make sure this particular device supports video
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the back camera
            if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back) {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    //println("Capture device found")
                    beginSession() // fatal error
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

// configure device for camera and focus mode


// start capturing frames
func beginSession() {

    // Create the AVCapture Session

    var err : NSError? = nil
    captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // Automatic Switch ON torch mode
    if  captureDevice!.hasTorch {
        // lock your device for configuration
        captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration(nil)
        // check if your torchMode is on or off. If on turns it off otherwise turns it on
        captureDevice!.torchMode = captureDevice!.torchActive ? AVCaptureTorchMode.Off : AVCaptureTorchMode.On
        // sets the torch intensity to 100%
        captureDevice!.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        // unlock your device
        captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
    }

    // Create a AVCaptureInput with the camera device
    if let deviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: &err) as? AVCaptureInput {
    // Set the input device
    captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
    }
    else {
    println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // Set the output
    var videoOutput : AVCaptureVideoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    // create a queue to run the capture on
    var captureQueue : dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("captureQueue", nil)

    // setup ourself up as the capture delegate
    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureQueue)

    // configure the pixel format
    videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
    // kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey is a CFString btw.

    // set the minimum acceptable frame rate to 10 fps
    captureDevice!.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 10)

    // and the size of the frames we want - we'll use the smallest frame size available
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow

    // Add the output
    captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)


    // Start the session
    captureSession.startRunning()


    func setState(state: CurrentState){
        switch state
        {
        case .statePaused:
            // is this correct code?
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = false
        case .stateSampling:
            // is this correct code?
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true  // singletons

        }
    }

    // sampling from the camera
    currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling


    // stop the app from sleeping
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true

    // update our UI on a timer every 0.1 seconds
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    func stopCameraCapture() {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

    }


    // pragma mark Pause and Resume of detection
    func pause() {
        if currentState == CurrentState.statePaused {
            return
        }

        // switch off the torch
        if captureDevice!.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            captureDevice!.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
            captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
        currentState = CurrentState.statePaused
        // let the application go to sleep if the phone is idle
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = false
    }


    func resume() {
        if currentState != CurrentState.statePaused {
            return
        }

        // switch on the torch
        if captureDevice!.isTorchModeSupported(AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
            captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            captureDevice!.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.On
            captureDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
        currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling
        // stop the app from sleeping
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
  }

 }
}
```